# How to code JavaScript function method returned by react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm, working on server-side rendering in a React app and I have the following JavaScript code. My `<FullPage action={this.handler}/>` component has an action property that is set to a function. When that function gets called, I want to set a variable (or even some state) in this component here. I can't figure out how to declare `handler`

```
export default (req) => {

    var myVar =
        <Router location={req.path} context={{}}>
            <FullPage action={this.handler}/>
        </Router>

    const content = renderToString(
        myVar
    );
    return `
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="App.css">

      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${content}</div>
        <script src="bundleclient.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
};
```

Comment: I tried putting ()=>{} in line but it did not seem to execute.  Could you provide simple example

Comment: Not sure but that can be because of server rendering. You are converting content to string, so that could be the issue. Not sure though